# html form input name for mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bfac9c5c44526e73f960e89"),
    "brand" : "Under Armour",
   "amazon" : {
        "order" : "666-666-666",
        "id" : "B072LNJPS1"
    }
...
}
```

HTML

```
<form....>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="brand">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="amazon.id">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="amazon.order">
...
</form>
```

NodeJs

```
    const myPost = request.body
    const query = { _id: request.body._id }
    const options = { upsert: true, new: true } 
    await model.findOneAndUpdate(query, myPost, options);
```

I have this error message because of the '.' in the field name

errmsg: 'Updating the path 'amazon.id' would create a conflict at 'amazon''

You have tips for the field name to match the model structure

Comment: Try encode before sending to mongo and decode after receiving it

Comment: JSON.stringify(myPost) ? or JSON.parse(myPost) ?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a complete answer, but you need to replace `"amazon.id"` with `"amazon[id]"` to match the nested structure.

*Reference: Colt Steele's "The Web Developer Bootcamp"*